# OAuth Scope required for Creating Github pull requests with Personal Access Token

Tags: github, github-api

I need to create documentation giving instructions to generate a Personal Access Token that will only need to create Pull Requests on Github.

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) describing the various OAuth scopes, but it is still not clear to me which OAuth scope(s) I need to select in order to be able create a Pull Request.

What OAuth scope(s) need to be selected for users to be able to create Pull Requests?

Answer (score 3):

From https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request:

> To open or update a pull request in a public repository, you must have write access to the head or the source branch. For organization-owned repositories, you must be a member of the organization that owns the repository to open or update a pull request.

Comment: So that would correspond with the repo OAuth scope? https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps

Comment: @JoelnonotthatJoel the `repo` scope worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The `repos` scope should be needed.

And, with the [GitHub CLI gh v2.22.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.22.0) (Jan. 2023), you can search from within your local cloned GitHub repository:

See [`gh auth status --show-token`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_status): it will display the auth token you are using.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1149246/199130513-abc96787-dd3c-42db-abe1-e11e9603066a.png]